# How do I set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env variable?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, email

I'm trying to fix a bug I'm seeing in a django application where it isn't sending mail. Please note that the application works great, it's only the mail function that is failing. I've tried to collect error logs, but I can't come up with any errors related to sending the mail. So, I made a example to try and force the errors. Here is the example:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('hi', 'hi', 'test@test.com', ['myname@yeah.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dmail.py", line 14, in <module>
    send_mail('hi', 'hi', 'test@test.com', ['myname@yeah.com'], fail_silently=False)
  File "/data/servers/calendar_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 59, in send_mail
    fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/data/servers/calendar_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 29, in get_connection
    path = backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND
  File "/data/servers/calendar_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/data/servers/calendar_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I managed to fix my test example by changing the code to this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/path_to_project',), DEBUG=False, TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False)

send_mail('hi', 'hi', 'test@test.com', ['myname@yeah.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

However, when I try to add those settings to send_mail.py, I'm still not getting any mail from my actual application. Can someone explain to me, clearly, how I setup the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE so that both my example and my application can see it? Failing that, can someone tell me how to setup meaningful logging in django so I actually see mail related errors in the logs? Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Do not set it from outside the application. Make a entry for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable within your `wsgi` file. Everytime your server will be started, this variable will be set automatically.

For example:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<project_name>.settings'
```

Comment: Sure, that sounds great. Do you have an example? (for the entry)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I checked my wsgi file and it already has:

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "oats.settings")

I'll try without the setdefault.

Comment: I tried adding os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'oats.settings', but no progress. Still getting import errors.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about it

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Mac or Linux? Then simply `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project_name.settings.your_settings_file"`
Make sure that if your settings file is in a folder, that there is also an `__init__.py` file in there.

On windows, I believe the equivalent is `SET DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project_name.settings.your_settings_file`, but I could be mistaken.

For django logging, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/

Comment: I'm on CentOS/Linux. My application is called oats and the settings file is called settings.py. So... I tried to: 

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="oats.settings"

But it had no effect. The test application doesn't pick it up.

Comment: In your first code block, are you running it from the Python interpreter or the django shell? If the shell, then make sure you have TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/path_to_project',), DEBUG=False, TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False in your settings file, then call the shell with the option --settings=oats.settings. Use the same --settings option when you run your server.

Comment: I'm using the interpreter, not the shell. I've tried to setup logging and logging works, but nothing related to mail comes out. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, I looked into the django code to find out where the settings for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in wsgi.py are executed.

```
$ python3
>>> from mysite import wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application() =>

In "django/core/wsgi.py"
     def get_wsgi_application() => django.setup(set_prefix=False) =>
In "django/__init__.py"
      def setup(set_prefix=True):
              from django.conf import settings
              from django.utils.log import configure_logging
              configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
In "conf/__init__.py"
      settings = LazySettings()
class LazySettings(LazyObject):
    def __getattr__(self, name=LOGGING_CONFIG):
      self._setup(name)
    def _setup(self, name=None):
        settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, settings_module):
        mod = importlib.import_module(settings_module)  

After which, we have settings.py imported and verified as below:
>>> mysite.settings.BASE_DIR            <<<===  verified
'/home/user/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite'
>>> mysite.settings.ROOT_URLCONF        <<<===  verified
'mysite.urls'
```

So it is first imported with configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG)