# Python gives errors when running Django tests

Tags: python, django

I got errors while running `runtests.py`. 
I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Django version 1.6.5. I copied code from github.

```
./runtests.py: line 3: os.environ[DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE]: command not found 
./runtests.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `(`
./runtests.py: line 4: `test_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)`
```

My **runtest.py** file:

```python
  import os
  import sys
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test-settings'
  test_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  sys.path.insert(0, test_dir)

  import django
  from django.test.utils import get_runner
  from django.conf import settings


   def runtests():
       if django.VERSION >= (1, 7):
           django.setup()
       TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
       test_runner = TestRunner(verbosity=1, interactive=True)
       failures = test_runner.run_tests(
           ['quiz', 'essay', 'multichoice', 'true_false']
       )
       sys.exit(bool(failures))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       runtests()
```

How could I solve these errors?

Comment: So you copied some code from somewhere and don't know how it works? And then you ask people here to solve it for you? I voted to close this question as it shows no research and basically asking for what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to execute this script on the command line as in `./runtests.py`, which is invoking a bash interpreter and hence why you're getting all kinds of weird errors. 2 ways to solve this:

1. Run it like `python runtests.py`
2. Put a shebang at the top of the file `#!/usr/bin/env python` then run it `./runtests.py`.

Comment: But localhost refused to connect

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39134636/6648243) you have to change

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test-settings'
```

to

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test.settings'
```

## Note

`test` must be your **django project name**. If it is not, change it accordingly.