# How to set environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django

I've bee trying to send a pandas dataframe to the django database, though when I try this:

```
user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
# host = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
# port = settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT']

database_url = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database_name}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database_name=database_name,
)

engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)
```

I get this:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, 
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

What could I do to fix this?

Edit: When I try the following command on `python mamange.py shell`:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_project.settings
```

I get:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-d6c3b615ad79>", line 1
    set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_project.settings
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thanks

Comment: It is not entirely clear why you need to set up the connection yourself. Django *already* has this logic. The only thing that you need to implement is a custom model field to (de)serialize the dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the DJANGO\_SETTINGS\_MODULE env variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134580/how-do-i-set-the-django-settings-module-env-variable)

Comment: @KenKinder I have this on my wsgi.py file: os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main_project.settings'), and still can't make it work

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How can I send my pandas dataframe to the database doing the way you suggest? Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server is Linux, you can set environment variables by typing `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_value` into your bash or sh console.

Edit: For Windows:

If you're using Powershell, the command should be `$env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= 'your_value'`.

If you're using batch (aka "cmd"), it's `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="your_value"`

Comment: @Filipe If you're using Powershell, the command should be `$env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= 'your_value'`.

Comment: @Filipe If you're using batch (aka "cmd"), it's `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="your_value"`

Comment: I ran python manage.py shell, then I tried:  set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_project.settings. I got invalid syntax

Comment: @Filipe Did you run the command from the Python console or a batch console? The later is correct, the former isn't.

Comment: I ran on the cmd

Comment: @Filipe Can you post the full error and what you did before you encountered it?

Comment: I opened the cmd, on the project path 
I ran python manage.py shell, 
I ran set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_project.settings 
then got File "<ipython-input-5-d6c3b615ad79>", line 1
    set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_project.settings
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think it means Python is trying to execute the command to set the environment variable. Try running the command to set the environment variable on a fresh cmd console and then running Python.

Comment: But I should do python manage.py shell before, right?

Comment: No open it after.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what's going on then. Apologies.