# Active Django settings file from Celery worker (how to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Dynamically )

Tags: django, redis, celery

[image]So I already looked around a lot for this but couldn't find a good answer. I'm using Celery celery and Django 3.2.13
., without django-celery package since newer versions of Celery don't require it anymore. I managed to set up tasks and execute them using Redis. Everything is working as it should there. However, I am integrating this in a existing, quite large, Django project. There we specified couple of Django settings files, not just one. We run different one depending on environment, for instance one for local machines and one for server. My problem is that I can't seem to be able to track down which settings file is "active" from the celery worker, which runs celery.py file in my project root (as documentation specifies). There the documentation requires to specify Django settings file like this:

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', "celery_test.settings.development")
Now this works, but if I move the stuff locally I need to change it to settings.local to make it work, and that every time. Reading settings object in runtime like I do in standard Django files didn't work since celery worker executes in a different process. So, using this situation, does anyone have any idea on how to dynamically fetch active Django settings file from celery worker? Or perhaps pass it in as a variable when starting celery worker? (like for Django, etc --settings=project.settings.local) Thanks!

I found the command line solution
When initializing the celery worker on the command line, just set the environment variable prior to the celery command.

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='proj.settings' celery -A proj worker -l info
```

but im getting an error

```
my commannd line 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='celery_test.settings.development' celery -A celery_test worker -l info --pool=solo
```

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=celery_test.settings.development : The term
'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=celery_test.settings.development' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='celery_test.settings.development' celery -A c ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DJANGO_SETTINGS...ngs.development:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcept 
  ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

[image]

Comment: This variable setting is for bash, you are using powershell instead.

Comment: Than how can I execute this on windows ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility shows how to do it, but it seems you can do it like this (i.e. instead of 2 lines): `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='celery_test.settings.development' & celery -A celery_test worker -l info --pool=solo`

Comment: so did you test it ?

Comment: Sorry i was so busy i will let you know tomorrow
I have tried 2 seperate line don't work , one by one

Comment: @Niloct its not working  set 
At line:1 char:63
+ ... t DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='celery_test.settings.development' & celery  ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double 
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

Comment: Sorry. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083153/152016 (try to put `$env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'celery_test.settings.development'` in a single line).

Comment: @niloct   , how will i run it  at same line or one after onther ? on windows cmd $env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'celery_test.settings.development'  celery -A proj worker -l info